# GeoTIFF for DEM has right coordinates but the actual dimensions are very smaller

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, dem, scale, dxf

The GeoTIFF file I have for Digital Elevation Model (DEM) has the following span:

N: 51 deg     E: -110 deg
S: 50 deg     W: -112 deg

The actual length and width of the area should be (89.1 miles x 69.1 miles) but it translates to 2 inches by 1 inch when exported as a .DXF and opened on AutoCAD and I'm having troubles Geo-referencing.

Does anyone know how to get the actual dimensions?

The reference system used on the GeoTIFF file is EPSG:4617. Is it because of the coordinate system?

[image]

Comment: "Georeferencing" is the wrong task here. You want to **project** the DEM, which has previously been georeferenced.

Comment: Which version of AutoCAD? Do you have Civil 3D or Map 3D?

Comment: Hi Vince. I'm new to all this. Could you elaborate?